# How to fix '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'readline'

Tags: python

I'm having problems reading a file. I am trying to use `readLine()` but it keeps giving me the error `_io.TextIOWrapper` object has no attribute `readline`. I can use read and the file first print statement would work but when I try to use readLine is gives me the error.

I am trying to read the first line as the canvas_size and not the whole file.

```
fp = open("25PrecentFill.txt","r+")
canvas_size = fp.readLine()
dimensions = [x.strip() for x in canvas_size.split(',')]
print (dimensions)
rectangles = fp.readLines()
print (rectangles)
for line in rectangles:
    [x.strip() for x in rectangles.split(',')]
fp.close()
```

Comment: your code shows `readLine` which is invalid format --> https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.readline

Comment: what would be incorrect about the format? As far as I can tell it looks correct to me. Im pretty new to python so it is still a learning process

Comment: python is case sensitive, your code shows you calling `readLine` but the operation is actually `readline`